# Wired WiFi extender gets a fraction of the WiFi speed

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I just bought an Edtiske Extender, WiFi Booster 1200Mbps Dual Band (5GHz/2.4GHz). It is wired into the LAN port directly to my main router. If I plug my computer into that cable, I get between 600 and 970mps. My WiFi signal from my main router is also the same speed, 600-900mps.

But this extender (and I have another different brand extender also wired in) both max out at 89mps  and that is sitting right beside the extenders. They are both set up in AP mode.

Why?

Comment: Can you return the extender?  That is what I would do for starters.

Comment: You might check online reviews and **answered questions** for that product, for example at Amazon, https://www.amazon.com/Extender-1200Mbps-Extenders-Internet-Repeater/dp/B0BYYRS9LC Note, in particular comments on lower-rated reviews.

Comment: There is a difference between Mbps and mbps…Please clarify

Comment: That extender's Ethernet ports are probably only 10/100, not gigabit. If that's not it, make sure you're joining the 5GHz band.

Comment: The extender description is...   up to 300Mbps for 2.4GHz, up to 866Mbps for 5Ghz.     And my main router tests at 674 Mbps. But I am getting 81Mbps on the Extender 5g.

Comment: As pointed out above, perhaps you should read the reviews. The ones with 1-star rating are very enlightening.